# Luhn Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, checksum

How can I improve or shorten my implementation of the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)?

```
    int digits;
    cout << "enter the numer of digits" << endl;
    cin >> digits;
    int Acc_num[digits];
    int shuma = 0;
```

The `shuma` variable is the sum.

I created an array to store the digits from the string `credit_card`.

And asked the user how many digits his credit card has, etc. (the `digits` int).

```
    string credit_card;
    cout << "enter the identification number" << endl;
    cin >> credit_card;

    // store the digits
    for (int i = 0 ; i < digits ; i ++ ) {
        Acc_num[i] = credit_card[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i <= (digits - 1) ; i ++ ) {
        Acc_num[i] -= 48;
    }

    // Double every other
    for (int i = 1 ; i <=digits ; i ++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            Acc_num[i-1] =  2 * Acc_num[i-1];
        } else {
            Acc_num[i-1] = Acc_num [i-1];
        }
    }

    //Sum digits
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= digits ; i ++ ) {
        if (Acc_num[i-1] > 9 && i % 2 == 0) {
            int mod = Acc_num[i-1] % 10 ;
            Acc_num[i-1]  =  1 + mod ;
        } else {
        Acc_num[i-1] = Acc_num[i-1];
        }
    }

    // the sum
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= (digits - 1) ; i ++ ) {
        shuma += Acc_num[i];
    }

    if (shuma % 10 == 0) {
        cout << "\nthis number is valid" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "\nthis number is invalid" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubling the even digits and subtracting 9 if > 10 would be mod 9 so a really simple, compact algorithm might be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDigits; i++)
{
    int   digit = digitArray [i] - '0';   // Char to number
    if  (i & 1)  // Digit 1, 3, 5 not 0, 2, 4 - "even digits" starting at 1
        if  ((digit <<= 1) >= 10) //  Double it, check >= 10
            digit -= 9;           //  Same as summing the digits
    shuma += digit;
}
int checksum = shuma % 10;
```

Comment: Code error - should have been >= 10, not > 10 but you get the idea. Break the problem down, solve with math where possible and don't write code that "does" things, write code that "takes care of" them.

Comment: One correctness consideration is that if the number is excessively long, `shuma` can overflow, which will probably ruin the checksum value. To avoid that possibility, you can change `shuma += digit;` to `if ((shuma += digit) >= 10) shuma -= 10;` and eliminate the `int checksum = shuma % 10;` line, since `shuma` will already be a modulo 10 reduced residue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could do all of those calculations in one loop. Also, all of the places where you do `Acc_num[i-1] = Acc_num [i-1];` amount to a no-op, so you could remove them.